# Using Swift what function to use as another function's parameter to raise x to the Kth power?

Tags: swift

Using this function in Swift:

```
func applyKTimes(f:(Float -> Float), x:Float, k:Int) -> Float
{
     return k > 0 ? applyKTimes(f, f(x), k - 1) : x
}
```

What function f to use as a parameter of applyKTimes to raise x to the kth power?

This is the third question at the bottom of this article http://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/

Comment: Please clarify your question, I don't get it.

Comment: Given that function applyKTimes, the question is : `Using applyKTimes write a function that raises x to the kth power`

Comment: it's the third question in the bottom of this article [link](http://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/)

Comment: I see. Without that article the question does not make any sense.

Comment: I don't know else to put it sorry

Comment: I would say f = (x)=> x*x but that's not right. You need f to be defined such that it takes a float and returns a function that takes a float and returns a float

Comment: personally, I vote for just using `pow(x, y)` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
applyKTimes( {x * $0}, 1, k)
```

will give you x^k

Comment: in ur answer what is x ? it is undefined identifier in xcode

Comment: use `let` or `var` to assign values to x and k. Or you can wrap it in a function like so: 
`func pow1(x : Float, k : Int) -> Float
{
    return applyKTimes( {x * $0}, 1.0, k)
}`